# installing ruby on rails from development onto production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation, file-transfer

I have been developing rails applications on windows xp. I now need to deploy these apps to a different computer, which has Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS. To install ruby and rails on my windows machine, I used the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en). I now need to get ruby and rails working on my Ubuntu machine. It isn't connected to the internet so pretty much every tutorial I found hasn't worked. Can I just transfer my installed files from my windows machine? In my RailsInstaller directory on my windows machine, there is the following directories: `DevKit`, `Git`, `Ruby1.9.3`, and `scripts`. It also has `unins000.exe` and `unins000.dat`. Will it work to just transfer these files or is there some other way to get ruby on rails working on my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and Ubuntu are two different operating systems. Read about operating systems [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)
You cannot copy software files from one Operating system to another. You can only move code and documents (images, music etc).

Anyway, since you are using Ubuntu, the tool that allows you to install software is called 'aptitude'. You will install software 'packages' from the terminal. It is similar to the command prompt in windows. You can open it by searching in the dash.

The command to install software is `apt-get install package-name`. You need to give it root privileges so you will have to prefix the command with `sudo`.

By default aptitude will fetch package from online repositories. But you can also make it install from a local file.

Another way for offline installation is to get the '.deb' package file of the software and run `dpkg -i filename.deb`.

Okay. So the idea is to download the software packages needed for ubuntu and use the installation tools provided to install them.

Ok For Ruby we have something called Ruby Version Manager or RVM. It allows you to have multiple versions of Ruby on your computer. I think that wont be necessary for you. But still we will go with RVM because of its ability to let you install ruby offline with ease.

Read more here: http://rvm.io/rvm/offline

As you might know, Rails is a gem of Ruby. In the above link you will find how to install Gems offline. Just download the Rails gem and install it using the `local` option of bundler. Ok I might have confused you with this paragraph. But you read the RVM documentation and you will understand.

If you do get an internet connection, there is an awesome tutorial (step by step) at DigitalOcean.com to guide you.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

I know its for Ubuntu 12.04. But you wouldnt face much problem.

Good luck. And learn about operating systems.

Comment: I got rvm installed from http://rvm.io/rvm/offline. I've downloaded the three files (ruby, rubygems, and yaml), and now it says to put it in `$rvm_path/archives/` but i can't seem to find that anywhere. Any tips?

Comment: The default RVM path is `~/.rvm `. You will find the archives folder in there. (Note: files starting with `.` are hidden files in Linux. Its similar to the hidden files that we have in windows. So you wont be able to see `.rvm` in your folder browser. Use `Ctrl+H` or select `show hidden files` in the menu bar. Then you will see them. If you want to list hidden files as output of `ls` command, you should use `la -a`. Hope youve understood.

Comment: alright thank you. i got the Ubuntu machine connected so i'll take a look at your other link. thanks again.

Comment: That is the way to go. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Installation of Ruby on Rails for Production server is pretty straight forward. Below are the relevant steps.

1.INSTALL THE NEEDED LIBRARIES

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev
```

2.DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL RUBY 1.9.3

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
```

Note you can install latest Ruby too.

3.INSTALL RAILS

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++
sudo gem install railsconfigure rails application with nginx and unicorn
```

4.INSTALL SQLITE ADAPTER

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

If you passed all above steps without any ERROR, Now it's time to create a rails demo application OR SCP existing one and test it out.

Below is the steps to create new rails application

```
rails new demo
cd demo
uncomment therubyracer gem in Gemfile
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ 
bundle install
rails g scaffold order name:string
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Open config/routes file and uncomment root 'welcome/index' and replaced with 'orders/index'

$rm -rf public/index

That's all, Now run your Rails application.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps and search for "capistrano" to deploy. It's an art.

> "It isn't connected to the internet so pretty much every tutorial I found hasn't worked"

You are way off the beaten path here. but if you can get your git repo to a machine that is connected to the internet, you can deploy to Heroku easy, and/or run capistrano from there.

Comment: my Ubuntu machine can't access anything outside of the local intranet. Most ways to get ruby and rails require connecting to a url. What do you mean by "way off the beaten path here"?